# Appending data from downloaded from the web in NSMutableData

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, csv, nsmutabledata

I'm trying to append data from a CSV file that I'm getting form the internet. Something is going wrong and I can't figure out what. My log is not returning anything for "Field" or "Value". I'm holding the data as NSMutableData and trying to append it. Am I overwriting it in any way? Something in the data storage/retrieval process must be going wrong... Could you pls take a look at this code and tell me if I'm doing something wrong:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CHCSVParser.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize parser = _parser;
bool isStatus;
@synthesize apendData;

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSString *myString;
    myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: apendData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    _parser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:myString]];
    _parser.delegate = self;
     [_parser parse];
}
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"data: %@", data);
   if (apendData)
        [apendData appendData:data];
    else
        apendData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
}
- (void)loadDatafromURL
{
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en-US&cat=0-13&date=today%207-d&cmpt=q&content=1&export=1"];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
}
- (void)parser:(CHCSVParser *)parser didBeginLine:(NSUInteger)recordNumber
{
    if (recordNumber == 41) {
        isStatus = YES;
        NSLog(@"ParsingStart..."); // Not getting this
    }
}
- (void)parser:(CHCSVParser *)parser didEndLine:(NSUInteger)recordNumber
{
    if (recordNumber == 50) {
        NSLog(@"ParsingEnd..."); // Not getting this
        [parser cancelParsing];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(CHCSVParser *)parser didReadField:(NSString *)field atIndex:(NSInteger)fieldIndex
{
    if ((isStatus = YES)) {
        NSLog(@"YES is working");
        if (fieldIndex == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Field = %@", field); // Just getting "Field = "
        }
        if (fieldIndex == 1){
            NSLog(@"Value = %@", field); // Not getting this
        }
    }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadDatafromURL];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you logged you way through to see what data you have at any given state? If so, could you please share this information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downloading and parsing - issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660722/downloading-and-parsing-issue)

Comment: Please only post your question once.